# how to define a pointer cast operator?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to wrapping an object and want to pass it as a pointer to functions. The object is known can be cast to limited types and I want to provide cast operator for these types. For example:

```
class MyInt {
  public:
    MyInt() {}
    MyInt(int val): int32_storage_(val), int64_storage_(val*2) {}

    const int32_t* GetInt32Ptr() const { return &int32_storage_; }
    const int64_t* GetInt64Ptr() const { return &int64_storage_; }

  private:
    int32_t int32_storage_ = 0;
    int64_t int64_storage_ = 0;
};


int32_t int32_add(const int32_t* iptr_a, const int32_t* const iptr_b) {
  return *iptr_a + *iptr_b;
}

int64_t int64_add(const int64_t* iptr_a, const int64_t* const iptr_b) {
  return *iptr_a + *iptr_b;
}


int main() {
  MyInt a(10);
  MyInt b(20);

  std::cout << "32bit a + b = " << int32_add(a.GetInt32Ptr(), b.GetInt32Ptr()) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "64bit a + b = " << int64_add(a.GetInt64Ptr(), b.GetInt64Ptr()) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

What I expected is to replace `GetInt32Ptr()` with a cast operator so I can call `int32_add()` like this `int32_add(&a, &b)`. I tried

```
    const int32_t*() const { return &int32_storage_; }
    const int64_t*() const { return &int64_storage_; }
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want the type to implicitly convert into another you have to declare that as an `operator` method:

```
operator const int32_t*() const { return &int32_storage_; }
operator const int64_t*() const { return &int64_storage_; }
```

Now, in order to call the functions just say `a, b` and they are implicitly converted:

```
std::cout << "32bit a + b = " << int32_add(a, b) << std::endl;
std::cout << "32bit a + b = " << int64_add(a, b) << std::endl;
```

---

Note: your function qualifiers aren't consistent (`const int32_t*`)

they all should be **`const T* const`**

also `std::endl` is generally wrong, replace it with `'\n'` - [reasoning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n)

Answer (score 8):

You're almost there, the correct syntax for the operator definition is:

```
operator const int32_t*() const { return &int32_storage_; }
operator const int64_t*() const { return &int64_storage_; }
```

Also note that as described [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator), you can also make these operators `explicit`, which is often desired to guard against unwanted conversions. It requires more verbosity, when doing the conversion, e.g. `static_cast<const int32_t*>(a)` instead of just `a`.

Comment: I have tried this, and got error like this:`
test.cpp:37:36: error: no matching function for call to 'int32_add'
  std::cout << "32bit a + b = " << int32_add(&a, &b) << std::endl;
                                   ^~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:20:9: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'MyInt *' to 'const int32_t *' (aka 'const int *') for 1st argument
int32_t int32_add(const int32_t * iptr_a, const int32_t* const iptr_b) {
`

Comment: Call it as `int32_add(a, b)`, the conversion operator will do the rest. No need to manually request the address.

Comment: Thanks @lubgr, it works! Because the parameter is a pointer so I hope it could be `int32_add(&a, &b)`. It more easy for reader knows the parameter is a pointer. Is that possible?

Comment: Well then you need to return a reference to the data member, e.g. `operator const int32_t&() const`.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the operator keyword.

```
operator const int32_t* () const { return &int32_storage_; }
operator const int64_t* () const { return &int64_storage_; }
```